# How to scale inline svg element with pure css without modifying the svg code itself?

Tags: html, css, svg, mermaid

Background: I'm integrating mermaidjs into revealjs like in the code snippet attached in the end. The graph generated by mermaid is computed on the fly and then injected directly into HTML as an inline svg element, but renders a very small image.

Question: Assuming the svg cannot be adjusted conveniently (coz I cannot find any mermaid option to set the viewport stuff), is it possible to stretch the rendered image with pure css approach?

````html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="https://lf3-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/reveal.js/4.1.0/reset.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://lf26-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/reveal.js/4.1.0/reveal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://lf26-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/reveal.js/4.1.0/theme/black.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://lf26-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/reveal.js/4.1.0/plugin/highlight/monokai.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="reveal">
        <div class="slides">
            <section data-markdown data-separator="^\n\n\n">
                <textarea data-template>
```mermaid
classDiagram
class Book {
    String isbn
    String name
    double price
}
```
        </textarea>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://lf3-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/reveal.js/4.1.0/reveal.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://lf3-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/reveal.js/4.1.0/plugin/markdown/markdown.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://lf6-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        const CODE_LINE_NUMBER_REGEX = /\[([\s\d,|-]*)\]/;
        const HTML_ESCAPE_MAP = {
            '&': '&amp;',
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&#39;'
        };
        const renderer = new (RevealMarkdown()).marked.Renderer();
        const escapeForHTML = input => input.replace(/([&<>'"])/g, char => HTML_ESCAPE_MAP[char]);
        renderer.code = function (code, language) {
            if (language.match(/^mermaid/)) {
                return '<div class="mermaid">' + code + '</div>';
            } else {
                let lineNumbers = '';
                if (CODE_LINE_NUMBER_REGEX.test(language)) {
                    lineNumbers = language.match(CODE_LINE_NUMBER_REGEX)[1].trim();
                    lineNumbers = `data-line-numbers="${lineNumbers}"`;
                    language = language.replace(CODE_LINE_NUMBER_REGEX, '').trim();
                }
                code = escapeForHTML(code);
                return `<pre><code ${lineNumbers} class="${language}">${code}</code></pre>`;
            }
        };
        mermaid.initialize({
            startOnLoad: true,
            theme: 'dark',
        });
        Reveal.initialize({
            hash: true,
            transition: 'none',
            slideNumber: true,
            markdown: {
                renderer
            },
            plugins: [RevealMarkdown]
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
````

Comment: I usually wrap my svg on a div then give it a class or ID, then call it on media query to adjust it If I cant find another way. Let me know what you've tried.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mermaid. Could you add the SVG (or part of it) to your question?

Comment: @Crystal I'm not sure if I understand what mean. I've tried setting stuff like width and min-width on the svg as well as the container, but ended up with no effect :(

Comment: @chrwahl The svg generated is quite complext. If you save and open the attached HTML, it should produce an svg (a UML class diagram) dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and this is the SVG element it generated:

```
<svg id="mermaid-1651128942542"
  width="100%"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  height="143.7999267578125"
  style="max-width: 117.17498779296875px;"
  viewBox="0 0 117.17498779296875 143.7999267578125">
```

So the `max-width` value in the `style` attribute is going to override any `width` you try apply to the image using CSS.

Would a 2D scale transform achieve what you need? Like this:

```
.data-markdown svg {transform: scale(2);}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I've tried that solution before posting this question. Yeah that will indeed scale the image up, but the problem is this approach will overflow the container and layer the image above other contents on the page, making them invisible.

Comment: You could remove the inline max-width setting with a bit of JS. Also the width and height attributes (would that help?)

Comment: You could add extra padding to the container so that the scaled up image won't overflow.